# how to store data structure matching .proto

Tags: java, android, data-structures, protocol-buffers

I have a android app that is quite simple it fetches data from the server using protobuf and then it lets the user browse the data tree (simplified)

Now I only ever want this data in my structure so I was using the protobuf reply (through autogenerated class) as my internal dataset.

problem is I want to be able to update some data in it and also get more data from the server and attach to the tree... this is impossible due to the data being immutable.

so my question is, how do I with as little computing power as possible store my protobuf messages as a changable data structures?

do i have to make my own corresponding dataclass-structure (seems like double work) or is there any other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach i've used is to implement my own types which mirror the protobuf types but which allow extra functionality such as in-place modification, and also implement a set of translation functions to convert between each pair of types. I then only use the Protobuf generated classes when i actually need to send or receive something over the wire.

Comment: It's just a shame, not only double coding work but also extra cpu power converting objects.

Comment: In android, instantiate objects is penalized with performance. This is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Your protobuf messages ARE changeable data structures. You modify them via the `Builder` interface and you can store them using Android local file storage or SQLite BLOB.

Refer to these examples:

- http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/javatutorial.html
- https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-protobuf-example

Comment: According to the documentation in your first link "The message classes generated by the protocol buffer compiler are all immutable". Can you provide an exmaple of how you use a Builder to modify an existing message object (without simply creating a new one).

Comment: `myObject = myObject.toBuilder().setFoo("bar").build();` ...I guess I don't see why "simply creating a new one" is such an issue.

Comment: I'm not saying it's an issue. i just think it's helpful to be clear that you're not modifiying the original object as it doesn't support iy.

Comment: Yes I need to change in the actual structure not just get an object that I can change.

Comment: So to clearify I have nested messages. And if I change the inner object with builder, the outer object wont let me reinsert it into the list